# InputStream readAllBytes from a specific index or point

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a basic proxy server for learning purposes. I want to read the headers received from the source server in `string` and receive the actual content in `byte[]`. Firstly, I read the headers in `string` using `BufferedReader`. After that, I read the bytes using `readAllBytes` which receives only half of the content from the middle to the end. Need help in extracting this data properly. I want to read the bytes from the point I finished reading the headers. Thanks

Simple version of my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

public class test {
    // Class to store the fetched content from the source
    private static class Content {
        String status = "", type = "";          // Store the response status and content-type
        int length = 0;                         // Store content-length
        byte[] data = new byte[this.length];    // Store the actual content in byte form
    };

    static URL url = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Content output = new Content(); // Custom object with fields only

            String proxyWebAddress = "http://www.bom.gov.au/";   // Default Web Address
            int clientPort = 3000;
            url = new URL(proxyWebAddress);

            String path = "/";

            String host = url.getHost();
            // Modify path slightly
            if (path.equals("/")) path = "";
            // Retrieve the Port
            int port = url.getPort();
            if (port == -1) port = 80;
            // Make the full url for the source
            String full_url = url + path.replaceFirst("/", "");

            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

            // Input and Output channels
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            // Send Headers to the source
            out.write((
                "GET " + full_url + " HTTP/1.1 \r\n" +
                "Accept-Ranges: bytes \r\n" +
                "Accept: */*" +
                "HOST: " + host + " \r\n" +
                "Connection: close \r\n" +
                "\r\n"
            ).getBytes());
            out.flush();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("HEADER: " + line);
                if (line.length() == 0) break;
                if (line.contains("HTTP/1.1")) output.status = line.split("\\s+", 2)[1].trim();
                else if (line.contains("Content-Type")) output.type = line.split("\\s+", 2)[1].trim();
                else if (line.contains("Content-Length")) output.length = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\s+")[1].trim());
            }

            // Want to get all the actual content from the point where the headers reading finished in the above loop
            output.data = in.readAllBytes();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("CONTENT: " + new String(output.data));
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

My current output:

```
LINE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
LINE: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
LINE: Server: Apache
LINE: X-Akamai-Transformed: 9 - 0 pmb=mTOE,2mRUM,1
LINE: Date: Thu, 29 Jul 2021 02:28:26 GMT
LINE: Content-Length: 39542
LINE: Connection: close
LINE: Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=HIT
LINE: Server-Timing: edge; dur=1
LINE: Set-Cookie: bm_mi=C0AE5D183B08AC192633EFB3C38BC6CD~4fVZCJN6lnAA5WMlK4MXtPUhEV7Wi7v0LC2GQIdM4jGDdRgYHY8rrCaKY7eIAuM2qYtnnqJ3iItpCvgZpB/wnIJT2EjdjpxeLTvUD2qR0VBxKc5MQHZnvkSlk1ruAUsTz8YS1wMHLD943/lVKDzI1oVk1gf8JxWD5VRZ6TKuVKJZCXjWjneC80kHJ7d2Fs9Caij18UZMk01PNAFaK+FcIY/TB6G6HFCDZvAxW0uv1OE=; Domain=.bom.gov.au; Path=/; Max-Age=0; HttpOnly
LINE: Set-Cookie: ak_bmsc=1D6ABC033A5FBFE968C2A3FA58DD0E00~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQAwUgF6p3Pqd6AQAAWnIX8Azd23YMvv0TB6JqHKYTHsfcHXK/Tn/MZWIjIiYuhVNZvRPj6X0rcSo7wwdE7xDuuvWSoLMBSj4cn4eQAPNVWAUcWQDPZYgPmXZxccTWOfliJI0RkbG5S2UwGiBcAuSf2wUSjshXGIWONcqMSnllPllr+gc1Yx5CneNuv9oL67yTICISabHsxzAndlmqkfBIKgrTGHwYeGpOP4i2PTmBW71XTci3V5fINYJy84ej7SAr1Gzd0qn95QhQiAcISESTmCPwhM/WXfDAyHV9+AYDdJ8wofpssF6XTJgSVbDYxg==; Domain=.bom.gov.au; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 29 Jul 2021 04:28:26 GMT; Max-Age=7200; HttpOnly
LINE:
s Forecast Area Map">NSW Forecast Area Map</a></li> <li><a href="/nsw/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="New South Wales Weather Observations">Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/nsw/observations/sydney.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for the Sydney Area">Sydney Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/nsw/observations/nswall.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for New South Wales">All NSW Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/nsw/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="New South Wales Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-vic"> <abbr title="Victoria"><a href="/vic/?ref=hdr" title="Victoria">VIC</a></abbr> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">Victoria Weather and Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/vic-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map showing Victoria at the bottom-right of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/vic/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Victorian Weather and Warnings">VIC Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Victorian Warnings Summary">Warnings Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/forecasts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Victorian Forecasts">Forecasts</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/forecasts/melbourne.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Melbourne Forecast">Melbourne Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/forecasts/map.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Victorian Forecast Areas Map">Vic. Forecast Areas Map</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Victorian Observations">Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/observations/melbourne.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for the Melbourne Area">Melbourne Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/observations/vicall.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for Victoria">All Victorian Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/vic/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Victoria Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-qld"> <abbr title="Queensland"><a href="/qld/?ref=hdr" title="Queensland">QLD</a></abbr> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">Queensland Weather and Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/qld-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map showing Queensland at the top-right of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/qld/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Queensland Weather and Warnings">QLD Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Queensland Warnings Summary">Warnings Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/forecasts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Queensland Forecasts">Forecasts</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/forecasts/brisbane.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Brisbane Forecast">Brisbane Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/forecasts/map.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Queensland Forecast Areas Map">Qld. Forecast Areas Map</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Queensland Observations">Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/observations/brisbane.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for the Brisbane Area">Brisbane Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/observations/qldall.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for Queensland">All Queensland Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/qld/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Queensland Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-wa"> <abbr title="Western Australia"><a href="/wa/?ref=hdr" title="Western Australia">WA</a></abbr> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">Western Australia Weather &amp; Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/wa-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map showing Western Australia on the left-hand side of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/wa/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Western Australia Weather and Warnings">WA Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Western Australia Warnings Summary">Warnings Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/forecasts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Western Australia Forecasts">Forecasts</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/forecasts/perth.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Perth Forecast">Perth Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/forecasts/map.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Western Australian Forecast Areas Map">WA Forecast Areas Map</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Western Australia Observations">Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/observations/perth.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for the Perth Area">Perth Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/observations/waall.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for Western Australia">All WA Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/wa/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Western Australia Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-sa"> <abbr title="South Australia"><a href="/sa/?ref=hdr" title="South Australia">SA</a></abbr> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">South Australia Weather and Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/sa-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map showing South Australia on the bottom-left of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/sa/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="South Australian Weather and Warnings">SA Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Warnings for South Australia">Warnings Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/forecasts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="South Australian Forecasts">Forecasts</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/forecasts/adelaide.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Adelaide Forecast">Adelaide Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/forecasts/map.shtml?ref=hdr" title="South Australia Forecast Area Map">SA Forecast Area Map</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="South Australian Observations">Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/observations/adelaide.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for the Adelaide Area">Adelaide Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/observations/saall.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for South Australia">All SA Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/sa/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="South Australia Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-tas"> <abbr title="Tasmania"><a href="/tas/?ref=hdr" title="Tasmania">TAS</a></abbr> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">Tasmania Weather and Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/tas-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map showing Tasmania at the bottom of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/tas/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Tasmanian Weather and Warnings">TAS Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Tasmanian Warnings Summary">Warnings Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/forecasts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Tasmanian Forecasts">Forecasts</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/forecasts/hobart.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Hobart Forecast">Hobart Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/forecasts/map.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Tasmanian Forecast Areas Map">Tas. Forecast Areas Map</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Tasmanian Observations">Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/observations/hobart.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for the Hobart Area">Hobart Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/observations/tasall.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for Tasmania">All Tasmanian Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/tas/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Tasmania Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-act"> <abbr title="Australian Capital Territory"><a href="/act/?ref=hdr" title="Australian Capital Territory">ACT</a></abbr> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">Australian Capital Territory Weather and Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/act-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map showing Australian Capital Territory on the middle right-hand side of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/act/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Australian Capital Territory Weather and Warnings">ACT Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/act/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Australian Capital Territory Warnings Summary">Warnings Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/act/forecasts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Australian Capital Territory Forecasts">Forecasts</a></li> <li><a href="/act/forecasts/canberra.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Canberra Forecast">Canberra Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/act/forecasts/act.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Australian Capital Territory Forecast">ACT Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/act/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Australian Capital Territory Observations">Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/act/observations/canberra.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for the Canberra Area">Canberra Observations</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-nt"> <abbr title="Northern Territory"><a href="/nt/?ref=hdr" title="Northern Territory">NT</a></abbr> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">Northern Territory Weather and Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/nt-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map showing Northern Territory at the top of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/nt/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Northern Territory Weather and Warnings">NT Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Northern Territory Warnings Summary">Warning Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/forecasts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Northern Territory Forecasts">Forecasts</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/forecasts/darwin.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Darwin and Rural Forecasts">Darwin and Rural Forecast</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/forecasts/map.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Northern Territory Forecast Area Map">NT Forecast Areas Map</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/observations/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Northern Territory Weather Observations">Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/observations/darwin.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Latest Weather Observations for Darwin Area">Darwin Observations</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/observations/ntall.shtml?ref=hdr" title="All NT Weather Observations">All NT Observations</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/nt/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Northern Territory Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <li id="sf-menu-aus" class="separator"> <a href="/australia/?ref=hdr" title="National Weather and Warnings">Australia</a> <ul> <li class="accessible"><h2 class="accessible">National Weather and Warnings</h2></li> <li class="decoration"><img src="/assets-140/img/bom/aus-thumb.png" width="80" height="70" alt="Map of Australia"></li> <li class="heading"><a href="/australia/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="National Weather and Warnings">National Weather &amp; Warnings</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/warnings/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="National Warnings Summary">Warnings Summary</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/majorcities.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Major Cities Forecast plus Outlook">Major Cities</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/radar/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Radar Images">Radar Images</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/charts/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Weather Maps">Weather Maps</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/satellite/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Recent Satellite Images">Satellite Images</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="/australia/flood/index.shtml?ref=hdr" title="Australia Rainfall and River Conditions">Rainfall &amp; River Conditions</a></li> </ul> <div class="sf-menu-pointer"></div> </li> <!-- <li class="no-menu"><a href="/global/?ref=hdr" title="Global Weather and Warnings">Global</a></li> --> <li class="last no-menu"><a href="/ant/?ref=hdr" title="Antarctic and Southern Ocean Weather">Antarctica</a></li> </ul> </div> </div> </div> </header> <div id="columns"> <section id="content"> <div id="current"> <div id="current_refresh"> <h2><a href="/australia/warnings/index.shtml">Warnings current</a></h2> <ul> <li><a href="/nsw/warnings/" title="New South Wales" class="tip">NSW</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/warnings/" title="Victoria" class="tip">VIC</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/warnings/" title="Queensland" class="tip">QLD</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/warnings/" title="Western Australia" class="tip">WA</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/warnings/" title="South Australia" class="tip">SA</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/warnings/" title="Tasmania" class="tip">TAS</a></li> <li><a href="/act/warnings/" title="Australian Capital Territory" class="tip">ACT</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/warnings/" title="Northern Territory" class="tip">NT</a></li></ul> </div> </div> <div class="other"> <ul class="sf-menu"> <li class="closed"><a href="#" class="noclick">Warning services</a> <ul> <li class="flws"><a href="/australia/flood/?ref=dropdown">Flood <br>conditions</a></li> <li class="trcy"><a href="/cyclone/?ref=dropdown">Tropical <br>cyclones</a></li> <li class="tsws"><a href="/tsunami/index.shtml?ref=dropdown">Tsunami <br>warning system</a></li> <li class="mwws"><a href="/marine/index.shtml?ref=dropdown">Marine weather warning system</a></li> </ul></li> </ul> </div> </section> <section id="banner" class="clearfix" style="background: #110f34 url(/gms/IDE00135.202107290130.jpg) no-repeat -70px -35px;"> <div class="mask"> <div class="radar"> <h2>National weather</h2> <p class="accessible">This is a dynamic map of Australia. Select one of the state links to view a forecast for that state.</p> <ul> <li class="nt"><a href="/nt/" title="Northern Territory">NT</a></li> <li class="qld"><a href="/qld/" title="Queensland" >QLD</a></li> <li class="wa"><a href="/wa/" title="Western Australia">WA</a></li> <li class="sa"><a href="/sa/" title="South Australia">SA</a></li> <li class="nsw"><a href="/nsw/" title="New South Wales">NSW</a></li> <li class="act"><a href="/act/" title="Australian Capital Territory">ACT</a></li> <li class="vic"><a href="/vic/" title="Victoria">VIC</a></li> <li class="tas"><a href="/tas/" title="Tasmania">TAS</a></li> </ul> </div> <ul> <li><a href="/australia/radar/" title="Australian Radars" class="tip">Rain radars</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/satellite/" title="Satellite images" class="tip">Satellite images</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/charts/" title="Weather maps" class="tip">Weather maps</a></li> <li><a href="/australia/meteye/" title="Interactive weather forecast" class="tip">MetEye</a></li> <li><div class="video-link-a hide-option"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div></li> </ul> <!-- Hack Fix to show 2 videos on the Bureau home page. --> <style> .video-link-c { margin-bottom: 10px } .video-link-c, .video-link-d { background-color: #edc319; height: 80px; overflow: hidden; } .video-link-c a, .video-link-d a { display: inline-flex; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: #036!important; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 700; margin-bottom: 2px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; } .video-link-c img, .video-link-d img { float: left; width: 120px; margin: 5px; } .video-link-title { float: right; margin: 5px; } </style> <!-- Remove the 2 divs inside and uncomment the iframe when ready to be removed. --> <aside id="advertising"> <div class="video-link-c" style="display: none;"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div> <div class="video-link-d" style="display: none;"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div> <iframe id="home-page-advertising" src="/includes/marketing.html" title="Marketing" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="display: none;">Marketing</iframe> <!-- <p>Advertising&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/advertising/">Why advertising?</a></p> --> </aside> </div> </section> <section id="today"> <div id="today_refresh"> <h2>Weather for Thursday 29 July</h2> <div class="city"> <ul class="sf-menu"> <li class="closed"><a href="#" class="noclick">City observations</a> <ul> <li><a href="/nsw/observations/sydney.shtml?ref=dropdown">Sydney area</a></li> <li><a href="/vic/observations/melbourne.shtml?ref=dropdown">Melbourne area</a></li> <li><a href="/qld/observations/brisbane.shtml?ref=dropdown">Brisbane area</a></li> <li><a href="/wa/observations/perth.shtml?ref=dropdown">Perth area</a></li> <li><a href="/sa/observations/adelaide.shtml?ref=dropdown">Adelaide area</a></li> <li><a href="/tas/observations/hobart.shtml?ref=dropdown">Hobart area</a></li> <li><a href="/act/observations/canberra.shtml?ref=dropdown">Canberra area</a></li> <li><a href="/nt/observations/darwin.shtml?ref=dropdown">Darwin area</a></li> </ul></li> </ul> </div> <div class="capitals clearfix"> <div class="capital"> <a href="/nsw/forecasts/sydney.shtml" title="Sydney forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Sydney</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">17.4&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">WSW 24km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">18&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Sunny.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/nsw/observations/sydney.shtml" title="Sydney observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Sydney.</a></p> </div> <div class="capital"> <a href="/vic/forecasts/melbourne.shtml" title="Melbourne forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Melbourne</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">13.0&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">N 15km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">17&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Mostly sunny.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/vic/observations/melbourne.shtml" title="Melbourne observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Melbourne.</a></p> </div> <div class="capital"> <a href="/qld/forecasts/brisbane.shtml" title="Brisbane forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Brisbane</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">24.4&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">WSW 17km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">25&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Partly cloudy.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/qld/observations/brisbane.shtml" title="Brisbane observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Brisbane.</a></p> </div> <div class="capital"> <a href="/wa/forecasts/perth.shtml" title="Perth forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Perth</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">18.2&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">W 20km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">20&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Showers. Becoming windy.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/wa/observations/perth.shtml" title="Perth observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Perth.</a></p> </div> <div class="capital"> <a href="/sa/forecasts/adelaide.shtml" title="Adelaide forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Adelaide</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">14.3&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">N 19km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">16&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Sunny.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/sa/observations/adelaide.shtml" title="Adelaide observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Adelaide.</a></p> </div> <div class="capital"> <a href="/tas/forecasts/hobart.shtml" title="Hobart forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Hobart</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">13.1&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">NW 19km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">13&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Shower or two.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/tas/observations/hobart.shtml" title="Hobart observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Hobart.</a></p> </div> <div class="capital"> <a href="/act/forecasts/canberra.shtml" title="Canberra forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Canberra</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">11.9&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">NW 30km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">13&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Sunny.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/act/observations/canberra.shtml" title="Canberra observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Canberra.</a></p> </div> <div class="capital last"> <a href="/nt/forecasts/darwin.shtml" title="Darwin forecast" class="tip"> <h3>Darwin</h3> <p class="now">Now<span class="val">29.1&deg;</span></p> <p class="wind">W 9km/h</p> <p class="minmax"><span class="max wrd">Max</span>&nbsp;<span class="max">32&deg;</span></p> <p class="precis">Sunny.</p> </a> <p class="rain"><a href="/nt/observations/darwin.shtml" title="Darwin observations" class="tip">0.0mm rain since 9am in Darwin.</a></p> </div> </div> </div> </section> <section id="services"> <h2>Our services</h2> <ul> <li class="awal"><a href="/watl/index.shtml" title="Weather and the land meteorological information for primary industry and natural resources management" class="tip">Agriculture</a></li> <li class="capw"><a href="/climate/" title="Climate outlooks, analysis and information" class="tip">Climate and <br>Past Weather</a></li> <li class="wain"><a href="/water/" title="Data, reports, forecasts, flood warnings and hydrometeorological services" class="tip">Water <br>Information</a></li> <li class="avws"><a href="/aviation/" title="Services for the aviation industry" class="tip last">Aviation <br>Weather Services</a></li> <li class="maao"><a href="/marine/index.shtml" title="Marine services for local waters, coastal waters and open ocean activities" class="tip">Marine and <br>Ocean</a></li> <li class="uvsp"><a href="/uv/index.shtml" title="Ultraviolet index, forecasts for sun protection" class="tip">UV and Sun <br>Protection</a></li> <li class="enin"><a href="/environment/" title="Environmental information access and discovery" class="tip">Environmental <br>Information</a></li> <li class="ruds"><a href="http://reg.bom.gov.au/reguser/" title="Registered User Services, additional services for registered and subscription users" class="tip last">Registered Users and Data Services</a></li> </ul> </section> <section id="more"> <div class="news"> <h2>News and events</h2> <ul> <li><a href="http://media.bom.gov.au/">Latest media releases</a></li> <li><a href="/inside/eiab/reports/ar19-20/">Bureau annual report 2019-20</a></li> <li><a href="/climate/enso/">Latest Climate Driver Update</a></li> <li><a href="/weather-services/announcements/">Service announcements</a></li> <li><a href="/climate/current/statements/">Special climate statements</a></li> <li><a href="http://media.bom.gov.au/releases/">All news and events</a></li> </ul> </div> <div class="special"> <h2>Specialised services</h2> <ul> <li><a href="/climate/change/">Climate change</a></li> <li><a href="/business-solutions/">Business Solutions</a></li> <li><a href="/research/">Research</a></li> <li><a href="http://reg.bom.gov.au/defence/index.shtml">Defence services</a></li> <li><a href="/wmo/">WMO activities</a></li> <li><a href="http://www.sws.bom.gov.au/">Space weather services</a></li> </ul> </div> </section> <section id="promo" class="clearfix"> <!-- <div> <a href="https://ideas.bom.gov.au/"> <img src="/assets-140/img/tile-bom-ideas.png" width="233" height="173" alt=""> <p class="caption">Help shape the future of Bureau services</p> </a> </div> --> <div> <a href="/australia/alpine/"> <img src="/assets-140/img/tile-alpine-feature-static.jpg" width="233" height="173" alt=""> <p class="caption">Australian alpine weather</p> </a> </div> <div> <a href="/app/"> <img src="/assets-140/img/tile-new-bom-app.png" width="233" height="173" alt=""> <p class="caption">Updated BOM Weather App</p> </a> </div> <div> <a href="http://www.bom.gov.au/strengthen/"> <img src="/assets-140/img/websitetile-strength.jpg" width="233" height="173" alt=""> <p class="caption">Strengthening our public<br />services</p> </a> </div> <div> <a href="/business-solutions/?ref=marketing"> <img width="233" height="173" alt="" src="/assets-140/img/tile-business-solutions.jpg"> <p class="caption">Business and Public Sector Solutions</p></a> </div> </section> <div class="clr"></div> </div> </div> <noscript><img src="http://www.bom.gov.au/akam/11/pixel_1f556eb5?a=dD1lNjcyODAwNDk1ZDY1OGM2MGJmNmM2NmM4NWYyZGRlMjZjYmE5YmIyJmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript></body> </html>
```

Comment: How does your code not work?

Comment: @Sweeper I updated my questions with my current output

Comment: And what output did you expect?

Comment: The full HTML file itself.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. The start of the HTML has been consumed by the buffered reader in advance (hence "buffered"), so you don't get them from the input stream anymore. How about only using the buffered reader to read the html?

Comment: Yeah, the initial half of the content gets consumed. I can only use bytes as I'm getting other file types of images etc.